# Devise - Login via phone number or email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I need to login to the application using phone number or email address. I am using devise 3.5.2 for authentication. As per this post([Devise sign up either by email or by mobile number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38221862/devise-sign-up-either-by-email-or-by-mobile-number)), i have implemented the following.

application_controller.rb

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected

def configure_permitted_parameters
    added_attrs = [:phone, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me]
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(added_attrs) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(added_attrs) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(added_attrs) }
end
```

user.rb

```
attr_accessor :email_confirmation, :login

devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :authentication_keys => [:login]

  def login=(login)
    @login = self.email
  end

  def login
    @login || self.phone || self.email
  end
```

config/initializers/devise.rb

```
config.authentication_keys = [ :login ]
```

Now if i try to login either by using email or phone number i am getting an "unauthorized" error. A sample request is as follows.

```
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"hCUuF5Ja9f37I4ZBSafGvCpgTnF1nKWf+q8aTEv28mW6vx3z+hIietmYjX9vi0/l/bjVqj0jDaV88mvmdXn9Vg==", "user"=>{"email"=>"jen@companyadmin.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}

 Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"uRnINI6Bogx3yeAP8WNpZB31jNOWnvvWVhHJg1BMZL2Hg/vQ5sl1i1Vy6zHXT+A9yi0XCN4hU+zQTLgpbsNrjg==", "user"=>{"email"=>"1234567890", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
```

For both requests, the response is

```
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 2ms
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Please share your view's code for email and phone while registering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the params you've shared, the phone or the email is being sent to the `email` named param. Instead it should be `login`.

If your view's code accepting the email or phone number is

```
<%= f.text_field :email %>
<%= f.text_field :phone %>
```

then replace it with

```
<%= f.text_field :login %>
```

This way, the param sent would be login and rest will be handled by your code.Let me know if this still gives you the error. Refer [this link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address). This implements the same except it uses username. Also note [modifying views](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address). This seems to your problem. everything else seems to be correct.

Comment: i have modified the views and now i am getting the following error.

PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column users.login does not exist

Comment: Do you have `find_for_database_authentication` method defined in `user.rb`?

Comment: Did you add `find_for_database_authentication` method? Refer the same [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address#overwrite-devises-find_for_database_authentication-method-in-user-model)

Comment: Glad i could help!!

Answer (score 2):

You should override default login behaviour.

User.rb (put this code in user.rb model)

```
def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
  conditions = warden_conditions.dup
  if login = conditions.delete(:login)
    where(conditions.to_hash).where(["lower(phone) ILIKE '%#{login.downcase}%' OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
  elsif conditions.has_key?(:phone) || conditions.has_key?(:email)
    where(conditions.to_hash).first
  end
end
```